# Changing Roughness value in python script has no effect

Tags: python, rendering, mesh

### I'm able to modify the roughness property while inside blender to achieve different effects (renders shown below)

### [image: picture of blender settings]

### [image: before setting roughness]
[image: after setting roughness]

However, no matter what I set the value in the code the output is always the same:
[image]

What do I need to do in order to apply the roughness in a python script and have it stick? The code sample is below where I'm setting the roughness to 1.

```
for m in bpy.data.materials:
    print("Going to clear out spec and metallic and roughness [%s] [%s] [%s] for %s" % (m.specular_intensity, m.metallic, m.roughness, m.name))
    m.specular_intensity = 0.0
    m.metallic = 1.0
    m.roughness = 1.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Aha!

So in case anyone else comes across this

to debug this I checked the property path by right clicking in blender on the property and selected "copy data path" which gave me this value:

```
nodes["Principled BSDF"].inputs[7].default_value
```

So I updated my script accordingly:

```
for m in bpy.data.materials:
m.node_tree.nodes["Principled BSDF"].inputs[7].default_value = 1
```

Comment: Instead of using magic numbers, you can use m.node_tree.nodes["Principled BSDF"].inputs['Roughness'].default_value = 1, Paste m.node_tree.nodes["Principled BSDF"].inputs[ into the console and hit [tab] for a complete list.

Comment: Note though depending on blender local language the inputs may be named differently. Both approaches are valid :)